# RouterLink don't adds href at first load from parent page template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I have root page with child pages, root page template has `[routerLink]` directives that route to child pages.
Something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home', 'auidiences']"></a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

HomeComponуnt has ROUTER_DIRECTIVES in directives section.*

When I navigate to page at first time links don't have hrefs, but if I update page they do and work. Any idias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is as I understand related to [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4809).
And one more - [user answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012#issuecomment-209613728).
OnInit doesn't fire and there is no component that works fine after router navigation.

To solve this problem you need to wrap your navigation call into `zone.run()`.

Comment: Looks like this issue should be fixed in RC.5 (when it is released)

Comment: It would be nice. How do you know?

Comment: I just looked at the closed date of the issue you linked to but it wasn't closed as "fixed" therefore my comment is misleading - sorry. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6867#issuecomment-230814944 mentioned it is working in RC.4 already but a comment below mentions it not working for in RC.4. It could be a mistake in the polyfills loading order though.